# Get-AzureVM Returns Nothing

Tags: powershell, azure-virtual-machine

I am using Version 1.0.1 Azure PowerShell module and it seems there is some breaking changes I cannot figure out.

I have logged into Azure and the Get-AzureSubscription cmdlet returns my two accounts.  However, executing Get-AzureVM's returns nothing even though the Azure Portal is properly reporting about a dozen.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I am experiencing same issue. Did you get it solved?

Comment: @Zec I too... Do you have multiple Azure subscriptions?

Comment: I doo. I solved this by doing what I needed in GUI. Powershell never worked  actually.

Answer (score 10):

Run `Add-AzureAccount`; this will load the Azure login dialogue, allowing you to sign in.

Once done, running `Get-AzureSubscription` should work as you'd expect.

Sadly no helpful error's displayed to say "you're not logged in; run `Add-AzureAccount` to login" if the command's run without you being logged in.

Comment: After registeing Get-AzureVM still returns nothing. Anything else that's required to make it work?

Comment: Not that I`m aware of... Do you have any VMs setup on the account/subscription that you logged in under?

Comment: I have an Azure cloud service which has several instances (VMs) and is managed by azure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to fetch ARM resources, please use “Get-AzureRmVM” cmdlet.

Get-AzureVM     - To fetch classic instances

Get-AzureRmVM - To fetch ARM instances.